# How do I add to my QUERY function to add an additional requirement?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 AVERAGE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(Data!D$2:E856<>"", "♠"&Data!D$2:E856&"♦"&Data!F$2:G856, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col2 
  where lower(Col1) contains '"&LOWER(A2)&"' 
  offset "&COUNTIF(Data!D$2:E856, A2)-6))})
```

I have the above formula that I am using. What this does is the following:
The last 6 times A2 shows up in either Column D or E, it accumulates the corresponding value in column F or G. Those 6 values are then turned into an average, as well.

I am trying to add one condition to this. I want it to only take those last 6 instances where column H and I are also something specific.
So when A2 shows up in column D, I only want to use the row if Column I is the value "X". When A2 shows up in column E, I only want to use the row if Column H is "X".

I am unable to get this implemented into my function myself and desperate for some help. One problem is that the "X" search is in reversed column order (ie. when A2 is in D, trying to search I...and when A2 is in E, trying to search G...which isn't the order those appear in the alphabet). Also just not sure where in formula this conditional even needs to go.

Data! just references the sheet I have my dataset dumped into, obviously.

Comment: TLDR. Please share a test sheet so you can be easier helped.

Comment: Happy to help on this, but as marikamitsos indicated, we need a sample sheet, with sample data and showing a desired output, to  make our work possible.